# Server IP or domain when connecting to backend?

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest

When you are connecting to your backend in e.g. a iOS application do you then specify your server IP or your domain when sending the request. What would be considered best practice? ([NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url ...] vs [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:ip ...])

Why i am thinking about using the server ip is because i have a squishy DNS service for my domain that sometimes causes slow connections.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DNS, and if you have to, use a service like DynDNS. If you code in an IP address and need to change it, you will have to update your entire app, instead of just repoint your DNS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Always use DNS so that the server can be relocated without updating the client.